# Proving that a matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a real-valued symmetric square matrix of size $n$ with the following structure:

\begin{bmatrix}
(n-1)\alpha_{1}^2 & -\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2} & ... & -\alpha_{1}\alpha_{n} \\
-\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2} & (n-1)\alpha_{2}^2 & ... & -\alpha_{2}\alpha_{n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
-\alpha_{1}\alpha_{n} & -\alpha_{2}\alpha_{n} & ... & (n-1)\alpha_{n}^2
\end{bmatrix}

I have the intuition that this matrix is always positive semi-definite. Empirically I am seeing that it is indeed the case but I am not sure how to prove it.

I have seen that the matrix will be positive semidefinite iff all the principal minors are non-negative. I am also seeing this empirically, but I am not able to show it formally. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you elaborate on your first answer, what is $\alpha$ in this expression $n \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm \alpha \circ \mathrm \alpha) - \mathrm \alpha  \mathrm \alpha^\top$ ? And by $\circ$ do you mean element-wise product?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ok I see now the equivalence. Then written in this form we can see $n \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm \alpha \circ \mathrm \alpha)$  is positive definite. But how can we derive that substracting $\mathrm \alpha  \mathrm \alpha^\top$ results in positive semi definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is equal to $D\left(nI-ee^T\right)D$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. Hence it is positive semidefinite, because by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
x^TD\left(nI-ee^T\right)Dx
=n\|Dx\|^2-\langle Dx,e\rangle^2
=\|e\|^2\|Dx\|^2-\langle Dx,e\rangle^2\ge0.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Given the equivalence you provide, could you elaborate what are the properties that lead you to conclude that the matrix is PSD? I see that a diagonal matrix is PD and that $ee^{T}$ is PSD.